# .Net 6 - UseCors for blazor

Tags: .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0

I am trying to build a blazor app that need to fetch some json from the client side but on a http source that I cannot convert to https and of course I have cors issues on chrome.

```
      Unhandled exception rendering component: TypeError: Failed to fetch
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: TypeError: Failed to fetch
 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSException: TypeError: Failed to fetch
   at System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetStringAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at CncGenerator.MachineDashboard.MachineDashboardController.GetStatusAsync() in C:\Projects\CncGeneratorV4\CncGenerator\CncGenerator\MachineDashboard\MachineDashboardController.cs:line 26
   at CncGenerator.Shared.MachineDashboard.OnInitializedAsync() in c:\Projects\CncGeneratorV4\CncGenerator\CncGenerator\Shared\MachineDashboard.razor:line 24
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
```

So I have found some posts that explain how to set thoses Cors by adding

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsAllowAll",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
                .WithMethods("GET, PATCH, DELETE, PUT, POST, OPTIONS");
        });
});
```

And if I understood correctly I should then do

```
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseCors("CorsAllowAll");
await app.RunAsync();
```

But I am a bit lost with the new way to do with .net 6 because app return a WebAssemblyHost and not a IApplicationBuilder as expected to be able to use the extension method UseCors.

How could I do to fix it?

Regards,

Comment: UseCors() is for the _Server part_ of a solution.  Is that "http source" your code?

Comment: _"need to fetch some json from the client side"_

Do you mean post from the client side? As @HenkHolterman already said, Cors is setup in Program.cs on server side, for your WebAPI or whatever you are doing. You dont need to setup Cors on the client side Blazor app.

Comment: Yes, I need to do a GET on a json that is hosted in a service that I didn't control and who is using HTTP and not HTTPS. How do I say to chrome then to bypass his default securities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to do a GET on a json that is hosted in a service that I didn't control

When that server is not configured to allow CORS requests then you're out of luck as far as using a SPA client is concerned.

You can call that service from your own Server. So make a pass-through endpoint.

> How do I say to chrome then to bypass his default securities?

Lots of hackers would like to know that too.

Comment: To give you a bit more context my project here is simply to control a CNC local machine and do not need to go over the web but of course the default securities are not made for those kind of scenario

Comment: Exactly. It does not change the answer. The Browser cannot do this on its own.

Comment: How do you explain then that I am able to do a request to this url by using postman or fiddler? (sorry I am a bit newbie on those topics). Btw, I have also tried to setup my blazor app in http in place of https to have an encrypted communication but it is not better.  The funny thing I have noticed here when I use ` return await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<MachineDashboardStatusRoot>( "http://192.168.1.11/rr_status?type=1")` he automatically try to call the **https**://192.168.1.11/rr_status?type=1 (in the code I use a http but it disapear in the comment :-) ).

Comment: The Browser enforces the rules. Postman does not run in a Browser. You can add an API server (see the Blazor Wasm + Hosted template), or use Blazor-ServerSide. The http/https issue is separate, I think it will be resolved when you call it from a Server.

Comment: Ok I have refactored completely my program to have the server side who will call this API.  And you where completely right it work with this logic. Thank you for your advices!